# What are the abelian extensions of $\Bbb C(X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

> I would like to have a precise description of the finite abelian extensions of the field $ K = \Bbb C(X)$. Typically, can we describe the abelianization of its absolute Galois group $G_K$?

**Thoughts:**

It is known for instance that the abelianization of the absolute Galois group of $\Bbb Q$ is $\widehat{\Bbb Z}^{\times}$. 
Maybe there is a geometric approach to my problem, via compact Riemann surfaces (equivalently, via smooth projective algebraic curves over $\Bbb C$). As mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188652/finite-extensions-of-rational-functions) question, the finite abelian extensions of $K$ correspond to "abelian covers" of $\Bbb P^1_{\Bbb C}$. I don't know if this is could be related to geometric class field theory, somehow?

My idea was to use *Kummer theory*, since all the roots of unity belong to $K$ and $K$ has characteristic $0$.
The map $L \mapsto L^{\times, n} \cap K^{\times}$ is a bijection between the set of abelian extensions $L/K$ of exponent $n$ and the subgroups $K^{\times, n} \leq H \leq K^{\times}$.
Under this bijection, if $L/K$ is *finite*, then its Galois group is isomorphic to $H / K^{\times, n}$.
Since $K$ is the fraction field of the UFD $\Bbb C[X]$, whose units are well-known, I think that we have
$$K^{\times} \cong \Bbb C^{\times} \oplus \Bbb Z^{(\Bbb C)}$$
where$^{(1)}$ $u \prod\limits_{\alpha \in \Bbb C} (X - \alpha)^{n_{\alpha}}$ is sent to $(u, (n_\alpha))$.
But then there are too many subgroups... and I don't know how to relate it to $\varprojlim\limits_{L/K \text{abelian finite}} \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.
It is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581995) that the maximal pro-$p$ quotient of $G_K^{\mathrm{ab}}$ is 
$\Bbb Z_p^{(\Bbb C)}$.

Some other notes:
the absolute Galois group of $K$ is the profinite completion of the free group of rank $2^{\aleph_0}$, according to the paper cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318690/).
The algebraic closure of $K$ is [difficult](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609504/what-is-the-algebraic-closure-of-kx) to describe, actually.
If we are interested in the $X$-adic completion of $K$, then  we get $\Bbb C((X))$, [which is](http://zerotal.github.io/texts/notes/2016-09-04-galois-puncture.html) a quasi-finite field (i.e. its absolute Galois group is the pro-cyclic group $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$).

Thank you for your help!

---

$^{(1)}$
For instance the subgroup 
$$H = \left\{
u (X-a)^{k_a} \prod_{b \neq a} (X-b)^{n k_b} \mid u \in \Bbb C^{\times}, k_b = 0 \text{ for almost all } b
\right\} \leq K^{\times}$$
corresponds to the abelian extension 
$L = K(\sqrt[n]{H}) =  \Bbb C\left( \sqrt[n]{X-a} \right)/K$.

Comment: I don't think actually that this is related to geometric class field theory, which focuses (if I'm not mistaken) on étale fundamental group of curves (while I'm interested in $\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb C(X))$, which is $0$-dimensional).

Comment: I don't know anything about geometric class field theory, but a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}(X)$ is just the function field of a curve together with a ramified covering map to $\mathbb{P}^1$.  So, studying all of these is essentially the same as studying the etale covers of curves of the form $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus F$ where $F$ is a finite set of points (the ramification points you must remove to get an etale map).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21755/

Comment: The above link is not really helpful, in view of the first comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266982/interaction-between-the-brauer-group-and-abelian-extensions).

Comment: Possibly related (?) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259926/

Comment: One important question, besides the description of the maximal abelian extension of $K=\Bbb C(X)$, is to know whether one has reciprocity maps, i.e. is there a $G_K$-module $A$ such that there are compatible isomorphisms $$A^{G_K} / N_{L/K}(A^{G_L}) \cong \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$$ whenever $L/K$ is finite and abelian?

Comment: (See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891646)